# Keeping getting 0.00 as an answer

Tags: c

I keep receiving 0 as my answer at the end. Please help

```
#include <stdio.h>
int Fahrenheit = 0;
double Celsius = 0.0;
double main(void)
{
    printf("This program will convert the temperature from fahrenheit to celsius.\n");
    printf("Please type in the temperature in fahrenheit followed by the enter key.\n");
    scanf("%d%",&Fahrenheit);
    Celsius = (5/9) * (Fahrenheit-32) ;
    printf("Your temperature in celsius is %3.2f.\n", Celsius);

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Look at what `printf("%d", 5 / 9);` outputs, and look for "integer division" in your favourite book.

Comment: Yeah - hands  up all those who know what the problem was before opening the question:(

Comment: @MartinJames Indeed very predictable ...

Comment: @MartinJames: Is an upvote on your comment sufficient, or do you want explicit feedback?

Comment: @Olaf lol, no, a beer will be fine.

Comment: I did take the time to look for a canonical answer to this integer division thingy, but no luck:(

Comment: @MartinJames: I'm very confident I saw eaxactly that problem already. But also cannot find it (maybe it has been deleted). About the beer: We actually have good wine im my region, but we also can get excellent beer from a neighbouring tribe (I'm not in France;-).

Comment: Then we all agree that it's difficult to find duplicates. So it's not so bad that sometimes one or two posters post anyway because they don't find an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Because of integer division, change `5 / 9` to `5.0 / 9.0`. Also, make `Fahrenheit` `double` and change `scanf()` to

```
if (scanf("%lf", &Fahrenheit) == 1)
{
    Celcius = 5.0 * (Fahrenheit - 32.0) / 9.0;
    printf("Your temperature in celsius is %3.2f.\n", Celsius);
}
```

Also:

1. There is absolutely no reason to make your variables global.
2. I have seen many peculiar `main()` signatures and now

   ```
   double main(void);
   ```
3. Ignoring the return value of `scanf()` would lead to potential undefined behavior. If I had a teacher that forbids `if` statements but requires `scanf()` I would quit with him and find a good instructor.

   But of course if I was learning how would I know that ignoring ٰ`scanf()`'s return value is bad? And that's the sad part, many even don't know that it returns a value or that it fails, for instance try this

   ```
   int value;
   if (scanf("%d", &value) != 1)
       fprintf(stderr, "Error, invalid input\n");
   else
       fprintf(stdout, "Ok, so your input is `%d'\n", value);
   ```

   type `"abcd"` instead of a number, what happens?

Comment: I have to keep Fahrenheit as an int and I cannot use if statements.

Comment: If you cannot use `if` statements you should not use `scanf()`.

Comment: May I ask why I cannot use scanf without if statements?

Comment: Because it's the wrong way to use `scanf()`. YOU MUST check for the return value.

Comment: This is an intro class to computer programming, therefore the teacher assumes that I do not know what an if statement is. She doesn't necessarily forbid it, she just assumes that I don't know what it is.

Comment: And why would you know `scanf()` before what an `if` statement is? Programming in general does not requiere a programming language, and you should learn that first.

Comment: I cannot answer that for you however, this college starts all intro programming classes using c language and the first commands they teach are printf and scanf. Those are the only commands I am supposed to be using for this assignment other than the main function and return function and what not.

Comment: So you can't desing an algorithm yet or perhaps you don't even know what an algorithm is, but you can use `printf()` and `scanf()`. I am terribly sorry, but this is really a bad way of teaching programming. You see, IMHO before learning those "*functions*" you should know that they are that, functions not *commands*. I understand how exciting it is to sit in front of the keyboard and write code, I really know I spend every day doing it. But I think you should first learn many fundamentals.

Comment: We have learned about algorithms and I do know what they are.

Comment: @Mattbox3 If there are limitations to an acceptable answer like "cannot use if statements", post them in the question.  As I see it, this answer well answers your post.  Next time you post - make clear limitations in the question.